# How to get a full permutation with permutation subsets

Tags: api, math, optimization, set, permutation

I have a problem involving permutations that conceptually I am having difficulty solving.

The problem is getting back data from an API *efficiently.*

I have 200 unique elements in a set that can be retrieved by the API. Each element crosses with each other element to create 1 unique permutation data point. Therefor I have 200x199/(2*1) unique permutations = 19900 crosses that the API can return.

I can get this data back from the API by making a call of at most 100 elements. If I include 100 elements in the API call it will return 100*99/2 = 4950 elements. All unique permutations of the elements in the call.

I am trying to write a program / algorithm that will suggest API call parameters that will return each unique permutation at least once in the least number of API calls possible. Rounding up if you can get 4950 back in one call it could take 3. But trying to demonstrate this in an algorithm has been difficult for me. And since each API call will definitely return duplicated data elements to the others I suspect its more.

The obvious starting point to me is to make a call for each unique combo but trying to minimize from there is stumping me.

Is there a common name for this type of problem? I am sure there is a more proper way to articulate this type of issue that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

How did you get 3? `19900/4950 =4.02`, so theoretic minimum is 5.

Simple appoach allows to use 6 calls - make quarters

```
A=range[0..49]
B=range[50..99]
C=range[100..149]
D=range[150..199]
```

and make calls A+B, A+C, A+D, B+C, B+D, C+D.

This method leads to triple formation of A:A  and other pairs, so excess is about 1.5.

Perhaps sophistic item remixing would decrease call count to 5, but I doubt.

Alike problems might be in algorithm section of SO, but I'm hard to make right query (due to my weak English)- team formation when player pairs never or seldom repeat?

Comment: That is a good approach! Thank you for your answer. You are right I messed up my math and minimum of  5 would be needed. I wonder if there is a proof for the bare minimum number of calls required. For now this will work for me though. Thank you!